# Converted sql query to linq but not getting any result

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

As I am new to Linq and Entity Framework.

The following is my working stored procedure which includes a value that is a comma separated string (the `SUBSTRING` clause)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SR.StudentRequestId, 
    SR.RegistrationId, 
    SR.Location,
    SR.PaymentMethod, 
    SR.CreatedOn, 
    C.ClassName, 
    CC.CampusName, 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(TSR.StatusId,0)=0 THEN 1 ELSE TSR.StatusId END AS StatusId, 
    SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT', ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(ST1.FromTime,'AM',''),'PM','') + '-'+ ST1.ToTime AS [text()]
         FROM dbo.StudentRequestTimings ST1
         WHERE ST1.StudentRequestId = SRT.StudentRequestId
         ORDER BY ST1.CreatedOn FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [Time] FROM StudentRequest SR
    INNER JOIN Registration R ON R.RegistrationId = SR.RegistrationId
    INNER JOIN Campus CC ON CC.CampusId = R.CampusId
    INNER JOIN Class C ON C.ClassId = SR.ClassId
    LEFT JOIN TutorClasses TC ON SR.ClassId = TC.ClassId
    LEFT JOIN StudentRequestTimings SRT ON SR.StudentRequestId = SRT.StudentRequestId
    LEFT JOIN TutorStudentRequest TSR ON TSR.StudentRequestId = SRT.StudentRequestId AND TutorId = @RegistrationId
    WHERE TC.RegistrationId = @RegistrationId
    ORDER BY SR.CreatedOn DESC
```

I have a requirement to use this data in a [PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) method that accepts a `IQueryable<T>` and I want to convert this SP to a LINQ query that returns a `IQueryable` (internally the `PagedList` method uses `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to perform server side paging).

**The following is my attempt so far, but I do not know why i am not getting to get the expected result as getting from SQL query. I think some thing is wrong in my below code. Can any one identify what is wrong in below code?**

```
var model = (from sr in db.StudentRequests
            join r in db.Registrations on sr.RegistrationId equals r.RegistrationId
           join cc in db.Campus on r.CampusId equals cc.CampusId
           join c in db.Classes on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
           from tc in db.TutorClasses.Where(t => t.ClassId == sr.ClassId).DefaultIfEmpty()
           from srt in db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(s => s.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).DefaultIfEmpty()
           from tsr in db.TutorStudentRequests.Where(t => t.StudentRequestId == srt.StudentRequestId && t.TutorId == registrationid).DefaultIfEmpty()
           where tc.RegistrationId == registrationid
            select new TutorDashboard
            {
             StudentRequestId = sr.StudentRequestId,
             RegistrationId = sr.RegistrationId,
             Location = sr.Location,
             PaymentMethod = sr.PaymentMethod,
             CreatedOn = sr.CreatedOn,
             ClassName = c.ClassName,
             CampusName = cc.CampusName,
             Time = string.Join(",", db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(p => p.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).Select(p => p.FromTime.ToString().Replace("AM", "").Replace("PM", "") + "-" + p.ToTime.ToString())),
          }).Distinct();
```

Can any one help me out for why I am not getting proper result from above linq query?

**Issue is that on adding below code to Linq I am facing issue, How can I resolve this**

```
Time = string.Join(",", db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(p => p.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).Select(p => p.FromTime.ToString().Replace("AM", "").Replace("PM", "") + "-" + p.ToTime.ToString())),
```

I had added this code because I want to get a single string from multiple row

```
1:00-1:30 PM, 2:00=2:30 PM
5:00-5:30 PM
```

**Like wise**

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. It's a language for ORMs. Instead of joins, your entities should have relations and mappings. You shouldn't have to write anything more than `db.StudentRequests.Where(sr=>sr.RegistrationID == registrationId).Select(...)`

Comment: On the other hand, you don't need LINQ to page over the results of a query. Create a view or function in the database, map *that* to a `TutorDashboard`   entity and query that entity using LINQ

Comment: I think I will be better to check you `sql Profile` then get the Generated `T-Sql` and copy that and paste in `Management Studio` then Run it , check the condition and Joins to know why is doesn't return any value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually I want to return the model on view side so i am binding it with TutorDashboard

Comment: Can any one brief me while posting the answer to this?

Comment: @Xtremcool that doesn't change anything. Turn the query into a view (without distinct/order by) , create an entity for it and map the entity to the view. There are a lot of similar questions

Comment: @osmanRahimi can u get me the proper steps to find out

Comment: @osmanRahimi I found the issue can you let me know how can i resolve this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I found the issue please review updated question and let me know how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was an issue in converting comma seperated code I had implement below code

```
var query = (from sr in db.StudentRequests
             join r in db.Registrations on sr.RegistrationId equals r.RegistrationId
             join cc in db.Campus on r.CampusId equals cc.CampusId
             join c in db.Classes on sr.ClassId equals c.ClassId
             from tc in db.TutorClasses.Where(t => t.ClassId == sr.ClassId).DefaultIfEmpty()
             from srt in db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(s => s.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).DefaultIfEmpty()
             from tsr in db.TutorStudentRequests.Where(t => t.StudentRequestId == srt.StudentRequestId && t.TutorId == registrationid).DefaultIfEmpty()
             where tc.RegistrationId == registrationid
             select new
             {
               StudentRequestId = sr.StudentRequestId,
               RegistrationId = sr.RegistrationId,
               Location = sr.Location,
               PaymentMethod = sr.PaymentMethod,
               CreatedOn = sr.CreatedOn,
               ClassName = c.ClassName,
               CampusName = cc.CampusName,
               StatusId = tsr.StatusId == null ? 1 : tsr.StatusId,
               Time = db.StudentRequestTimings.Where(p => p.StudentRequestId == sr.StudentRequestId).Select(p => p.FromTime.ToString().Replace("AM", "").Replace("PM", "") + "-" + p.ToTime)
               }).ToList().GroupBy(p => new { p.StudentRequestId }).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();


          var model = query.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TutorDashboard
           {
              StudentRequestId = x.StudentRequestId,
              RegistrationId = x.RegistrationId,
              Location = x.Location,
              PaymentMethod = x.PaymentMethod,
              CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn,
              ClassName = x.ClassName,
              CampusName = x.CampusName,
              StatusId = x.StatusId == null ? 1 : x.StatusId,
              Time = string.Join(",", x.Time),
               }).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 1);
```

May this code will be helpful to some who need comma separated value with multiple left join